# html table in a table controlling col widths

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table (parent) that has several rows with 6 columns each. In between each of these there could be a table(child) with several rows that only have 4 columns each. I want these rows to be centered and about 80% the width of row above them. I also don't want the cells in the parent rows to control the size/spacing of the cells in the child rows. There is also some javascript that controls the display attribute of the child rows/cells.

This shows a list of orders in the parent rows with each orders detail/line items in the child rows. I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to make the width and the cell size/spacing of the child rows independent of the parent row/cells. And to make it a little more complicated, the javascript changes the cells in the child rows to display: none; or display: block; to toggle between visible or not. When the display is set to block it always forces that table into the first cell width of parent row.

I hope this makes sense. Any suggestions on how to make the child table independent would be great.

Comment: Can you show us your code?